# Unable to send logs from kinesis firehose to opensearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-kinesis-firehose, opensearch

I have a workflow, where:

- All cloudwatch logs will be streamed to Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream.
- From Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream, it will be sent to Opensearch.

However, **Kinesis is failed to put data to opensearch and returning the error**:

```
The Amazon OpenSearch Service cluster returned a JsonParseException. Ensure that the data being put is valid.
```

I have tried **all available Lambda blueprints for firehose** to transform records as well, but no luck.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Any luck on this, I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I raised an AWS ticket and got this reply

> I understand that you are implementing the below data flow:
>
> Logger Lambda--> Cloudwatch log group--> Firehose (Lambda
> transformation) --> Streaming to Opensearch
>
> you encountered the below error message from OpenSearch services:
>
> ### -- Error Message: The Amazon OpenSearch Service cluster returned a JsonParseException. Ensure that the data being put
> is valid. Error Code: OS.JsonParseException
>
> As per the error message, it indicated the data being sent to the
> OpenSearch cluster is not a valid JSON object. Cloudwatch log group
> will send multiple logs in one record against firehose, which resulted
> invalid JSON being sent to the OpenSearch cluster, because OpenSearch
> only accepts single JSON object as the data format. Meanwhile,
> Firehose does not allow passing back more records than what was passed
> to its transformation Lambda function. Therefore, it is not possible
> to use the current pipeline.

Suggested workarounds by AWS support

1. CloudWatch Logs -> Kinesis Data Stream -> Lambda -> Firehose -> OpenSearch
2. CloudWatch logs -> Lambda  -> Firehose -> OpenSearch
3. CloudWatch logs (subscription filter) -> OpenSearch

I would like to know your thoughts on this.